# Finding parameters for which a function/symbol is defined

Tags: functions, symbols

Suppose I have a symbol/function defined pointwise like in

```
f[1, 5] = 3
f[3] = 7
f[2, 3.4] = 8
```

By executing `?f` I can see the definition of `f`, i.e.

```
Global`f
f[3]=7
f[1,5]=3
f[2,3.4]=8
```

How can I get a list of all parameter tuples for which the function is defined? In my example I would like to obtain the list

```
{{1,5},{3},{2,3.4}}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DownValues[f] to get the list of rules, the structure of which uses HoldPattern to prevent the evaluation.

```
DownValues[f]
{HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 7, HoldPattern[f[1, 5]] :> 3, HoldPattern[f[2, 3.4]] :> 8}
```

If you replace f with List and extract the correct part of the expressions that should return what you are after:

```
(DownValues[f] /. f -> List)[[All, 1, 1, All]]
{{3}, {1, 5}, {2, 3.4}}
```

Note that the list has been sorted (in how DownValues reports the structure).

Comment: I'd use `Cases[DownValues[f], HoldPattern[f[val__]] :> {val}, ∞]` myself.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need. I wasn't aware of `DownValues[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis, I was sure that someone would produce a smarter looking version! And that looks a lot neater than having to work out which levels to take the Part of, which is what I generally end up doing.

Comment: @cgogolin, there are UpValues, DownValues, SubValues and OwnValues, all of which let you get at various types of definitions.

Comment: Why do you put the last `All` in `[[All, 1, 1, All]]`? For any list `f` it is true that `f[[All]] === f`, after all.

Comment: @JoMo, no cunning reason here, I agree it is unnecessary